# Why is my Excel 2010 window always on top?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, always-on-top

I guess I have exactly the same issue as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/405246/why-is-my-microsoft-word-window-always-on-top-of-other-windows) poster, but in Excel.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Are you running a routine that pops up an alert or something?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File>Options>Customize Ribbon. Then hit reset. Should be all set after that.

Comment: Please explain how resetting the ribbon fixes the problem.

Comment: Didn't work and lost all customization.

Answer (score -1):

I tried resetting the ribbon and it didn't work.

The quickest solution I could find was closing and reopening the Excel file.

Not going to waste more time on this right now.

Comment: Hey downvoter, would you please care explaining the downvote? 
My answer carries a solution. Maybe it's not *the final* solution but it's not a discriminant here because the cause of the problem could be buried deep in MS Office code, so unless you expect every answer to include a MS Office reverse engineering session you should accept it as a good when it gives you the best achievable solution, and at the very least *not* downvote it, unless you shared with us a good reason for that.
I guess some people never learn when it's time to say thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Hit the bottom right "show desktop" in Win 7 and bring back up the windows as you see fit.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. can you elaborate further on your answer please? also if possible include a screenshot.

Answer (score -2):

This happens on MacOS X as well, and while the systems are obviously different, it could be the same reason - the damned ribbon.  Try disabling the ribbon in the preferences (if possible - you can do this on the Mac at least), and the behaviour may go away.

Comment: The Office Ribbon cannot be disabled on the Windows version of Office.

Comment: @Ramhound: It absolutely can be disabled on all versions of office (including those in Windows) from 2007 to 2016 using the VBA macro ```Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"", False)"```, but also in the preferences in some earlier versions.  You can also minimize it on many versions.

Comment: There is a difference between disabling the Ribbon and simply not showing it.  My comment was simply to illistrate the fact there is no preference option to disable the ribbon bar within Office running on Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound: the preference on the Mac 2010 version does *exactly* what the VBA macro also does - disables the toolbar.  There is no functional meaning to "a difference between disabling the Ribbon and simply not showing it" - the Ribbon performs no computations and takes no actions, it simply takes up screen space.  The only thing it *does* is "be shown", so "not showing" and "disabling" are semantically equivalent.

Answer (score -3):

Firstly try restarting Excel.

If that doesn't work, try restarting the computer.

Finally, right-click on "Microsoft Excel" in the start bar, and make sure that "Always on top" is deselected.

Comment: Where exactly is the always on top selection? I can't seem to find it...

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm running Windows 7 Professional and Excel 2010 32bit.

Comment: Did you try the first two steps?

Comment: I can't find how to get that menu in Windows 7.

Comment: the first two solves it, but after a while the same issue pops up again.

Comment: There is no such thing as always on top.

Comment: Well to be correct there is  no "always on top" in newer versions of Windows