# Word Document 2010 always on top

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

My word document stays always on top, so when I try to open any program when the word document is opened, it's being behind it and not on it. It is very frustrating.

I have searched on the options any checkbox that is responsible for it but nothing. And I have searched in google, but no one really helped.

Can some one help me to remove it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the previous post on this site regarding the problem?  Check here and see if the suggested fixes work for you:  [Why is my Microsoft Word window always on top of other windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/405246/why-is-my-microsoft-word-window-always-on-top-of-other-windows)

Comment: Yes, I have seen it but no help...